# Running out of JDBC connections when loading entity in StreamingResponseBody

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jdbc

I am currently working on a streaming service which I want to use to play audio files on the client in a more efficient manner. In order to do so I have an endpoint which returns a `StreamingRepsonseBody` and only the requested bytes of an audio file.

However, After streaming an audio file however, I run into the problem of getting a `CannotGetJdbcConnectionException` for *any* request I make towards the server (find the full stack trace below).

It seems that the database connection is never getting closed. The exception gets (usually) thrown after 10 requests (I think this is also the limit of open connections).

I was able to "*solve*" this problem by just *not* making a call to the database but this means that the client has to send me the information which I'd normally fetch from the database

#### The Working Endpoint

If I get the `bucketName` and `bucketFilename` via `@RequestParam`, I do not need to fetch the `TrackEntity` from the database and the streaming endpoint works as expected:

```java
@RequestMapping(
        value = "/tracks/{trackId}/play",
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE
)
public StreamingResponseBody playTrack(
        @PathVariable("trackId") Long trackId,
        @RequestHeader("Range") String range,
        @RequestParam("bucketName") String bucketName,
        @RequestParam("bucketFilename") String bucketFilename
) {
    String[] rangeValues = range.split("=")[1].split("-");
    int rangeStart = Integer.parseInt(rangeValues[0]);
    int rangeEnd = Integer.parseInt(rangeValues[1]);
    int rangeSize = rangeEnd - rangeStart;

    InputStreamResource inputStreamResource = this.trackService
            .readChunk(bucketName, bucketFilename, rangeStart);

    return outputStream -> {
        try (InputStream inputStream = inputStreamResource.getInputStream()) {
            StreamUtils.copyRange(inputStream, outputStream, 0, rangeSize);
        }
    };
}
```

#### The Broken Endpoint

This is how it *should* be. Using the `trackService` I want to load the `TrackEntity` from the database. However, this is where the exception comes from.

```java
@RequestMapping(
        value = "/tracks/{trackId}/play",
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE
)
public StreamingResponseBody playTrack(
        @PathVariable("trackId") Long trackId,
        @RequestHeader("Range") String range
) {
    String[] rangeValues = range.split("=")[1].split("-");
    // Fetch TrackEntity from the database
    TrackEntity track = this.trackService.getTrack(trackId);
    String bucketName = track.getBucketName();
    String bucketFilename = track.getBucketFilename();

    int rangeStart = Integer.parseInt(rangeValues[0]);
    int rangeEnd = Integer.parseInt(rangeValues[1]);
    int rangeSize = rangeEnd - rangeStart;

    InputStreamResource inputStreamResource = this.trackService
            .readChunk(bucketName, bucketFilename, rangeStart);

    return outputStream -> {

        try (InputStream inputStream = inputStreamResource.getInputStream()) {
            StreamUtils.copyRange(inputStream, outputStream, 0, rangeSize);
        }
        System.out.println(String.format("Fetched %.4f MB", (rangeSize / Math.pow(1024.0, 2))));
    };
}
```

This is the implementation of `getTrack()`. Nothing exciting here.

```java
public TrackEntity getTrack(Long trackId) {
    return this.trackRepository.findById(trackId)
            .orElseThrow(ResourceNotFoundException::new);
}
```

#### Full Stack Trace

This is the complete stack trace of the exception thrown.

```
org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30000ms.
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:82) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:612) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:669) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:700) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:712) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcTemplate.java:790) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JdbcTokenStore.readAccessToken(JdbcTokenStore.java:160) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices.loadAuthentication(DefaultTokenServices.java:229) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$5a1f25c.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:685) ~[spring-aop-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$76cd39c0.loadAuthentication(<generated>) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationManager.authenticate(OAuth2AuthenticationManager.java:83) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:150) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter.doFilter(ChannelProcessingFilter.java:157) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at io.ear.spring.config.SimpleCORSFilter.doFilter(SimpleCORSFilter.java:36) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1591) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30000ms.
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createTimeoutException(HikariPool.java:697) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:196) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:161) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:128) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:158) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:116) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:79) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    ... 64 common frames omitted
```

#### Stack Trace to "Apparent connection leak detected"

Thanks to [M. Deinum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2696260) I was able to find the leak in the first place by setting in my `application.properties` the following:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG
spring.datasource.hikari.leak-detection-threshold=15000
```

Which led me to the exception:

```
java.lang.Exception: Apparent connection leak detected
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:128) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.java:38) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:104) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:134) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.connection(SessionImpl.java:462) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:282) ~[spring-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:266) ~[spring-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle.doGetConnection(HibernateJpaDialect.java:430) ~[spring-orm-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
   ...
```

Comment: You are using the `TaskExecutor` for which the error clearly states you shouldn't be using. Eventually, you will run out of resources (as this executor creates new threads when needed and your streaming never ends). Next to that, due to the never-ending, after about 10 requests (depending on your connection pool size) your application is unusable as there are no more connections left to spare.

Comment: @M.Deinum Which executor would be suitable in my case?

Comment: I don't know your case. It depends on the server, the use-case etc. there is no easy answer. Check the implementations and pick one.

Comment: @M.Deinum So, I actually don't hink that the `SimpleTaskExecutor` is the problem. There is only one request every 10 seconds from a single client and this simply cannot be too much. Unless there is some other issue I am not seeing.

Comment: It isn't but it will be in the future as threads aren't reused and only created but not cleaned up. Doesn't matter if there is 1 request every 10 seconds, you are streaming data and as long as the data is streaming the connection is open.

Comment: @M.Deinum Now I am confused. These are separate requests - at leass that's what I thought. My client makes a new GET request every time it requires a new chunk of the data. The reason why I use a `StreamingResponseBody` is because that data comes from a Cloud Storage and I am just forwarding the byte-stream to the client.

Comment: And each request will start streaming and will start a new thread and occupy a connection. So if things aren't properly cleaned up (or if resources are still held for whatever reason) it will eventually all start to fail. You should at least change the `TaskExecutor` and make sure you are properly closing things (like the `InputStream`). Also you should obtain the inputstream inside the `StreamingResponseBody` and not outside of it. Finally I would suggest using `StreamUtils.copyRange` instead of your own logic.

Comment: Please add the full stacktrace instead of a snippet as it is important to see where the exception comes from exactly. Looking at the leak detection it appears when reading the track. However the stakctrace clearly shows a `JdbcTemplate` so you must be mixing both JPA and JDBC in your code. Show that JDBC code as well.

Comment: @M.Deinum I just updated the stack trace.

Comment: I didn't mean the one from the leak-detection, but the initial one you posted.

Comment: @M.Deinum Sorry, my mistake. Updated it :)

Comment: Looks like both stack traces are a symptom of something else. There must be code in your codebase that gets a connection and never releases is. There is some JDBC code somewhere that works around all the spring mechanism (apparently) and never closes a connection.

Comment: @M.Deinum There isn't really any more code. The only code I didn't post is from the `storageSerice` but that's not really interesting in that case. Any idea how I can track that issue down?

Comment: @M.Deinum I have just removed the `trackService#getTrack()` call and now it works. It seems that the problem is this particular call.

Comment: Just realized that you are probably using JPA and Spring Data JPA. By default the open-session-in-view pattern is enabled (I think weird things when driving my car :) ). Try adding `spring.jpa.open-in-view=false` to your configuration. This will disable the open-session-in-view and won't early  open a session nor will it keep it open.

Comment: @M.Deinum You're the man! This seems to work. In fact, only recently I was wondering whether I should look into that warning at the startup of the server. It's weird that this is enabled on default even though it seems to have serious performance impact. That thought in your car was great :D If you could add this to your answer I'd be happy to accept it. :)

Comment: Good to hear it is resolved.However, I would also suggest you register a bug with Spring and/or Spring Boot. I would expect the open-in-view to be closed in an async fashion and I would consider this a bug or regression from the Spring (Boot) point-of-view.

Comment: @M.Deinum Alright, I'll file a bug today in the late afternoon. Thanks for your help! I guess I would have never found this alone ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. First don't use the `SimpleTaskExecutor` that will lead to issues later on (it will create `Thread` objects for each incoming request and might not clean them up properly.
2. Your code might have a resource leak by not closing the `InputStream` and/or by going into a continuous loop.
3. You are using JPA and by default the `spring.jpa.open-in-view` property is enabled (you will get a warning on startup if you didn't set it explicitly). You might want to switch this to `false` to only open a session when needed.

To fix 1, just remove your bean definition and Spring Boot will configure a proper `TaskExecutor` for you (out-of-the-box).

For number 2 rewrite the code in your controller to prevent resource leaks.

```java
@GetMapping(
        value = "/tracks/{trackId}/play",
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE
)
public StreamingResponseBody playTrack(
        @PathVariable("trackId") Long trackId,
        @RequestHeader("Range") String range
) {

    String[] rangeValues = range.split("=")[1].split("-");

    int rangeStart = Integer.parseInt(rangeValues[0]);
    int rangeEnd = Integer.parseInt(rangeValues[1]);

    return outputStream -> {
        InputStreamResource inputStreamResource = this.trackService.playTrack(trackId);
        try (InputStream inputStream = inputStreamResource.getInputStream()) {
          StreamUtils.copyRange(inputStream, outputStream, rangeStart, rangeEnd);        
        }       
    };
}
```

This code will close the `InputStream` and the `StreamUtils.copyRange` will never go into an infinite loop (and it cleans up your code).

Number 3 is quite easy to fix add the following to your `application.properties`.

```
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false
```

This might, however, have implications for other parts of your application not working properly anymore. Especially if you have a view and rely on the open session in view pattern to automatically retrieve not yet retrieved data (i.e. lazy relations in your entities).

Comment: I have changed the code to your implementation. I am still not sure which `TaskExecutor` to use but I've now switched over to `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` (and `ConcurrentTaskExecutor`). I have also set `spring.mvc.async.request-timeout=3600000` in my config because I ran into a timeout issue however.. I still get the same behavior. After a few requests, the server freezes. I guess this might still have to do with the `TaskExecutor`.

Comment: As I stated in the answer, remove the bean definition for the TaskExecutor. Spring Boot will configure one for you out-of-the-box. Enable debug or trace logging to see what happens. You also might want to enable leak detection on your connection pool, assuming you are using the spring boot configured one.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misunderstood the out-of-the-box remark. I removed it and added TRACE logging as well as `spring.datasource.hikari.leak-detection-threshold=15000`. You were right there. It seems that there is in fact a leak and it is coming from `trackService.playTrack` which, looks into my database first in order to get the location of the file (Cloud Storage) after that I create and return the `InputStreamResource`. It seems that the connection to the database never gets closed as `CannotGetJdbcConnectionException` indicates. The question is: How can I do this right? :D

Comment: Please add the code for that service to your question.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I didn't find time yesterday to get onto it. So, I've updated the code to my question to what it looks now. The `@Service TrackService` in this case does not really do a lot except loading a `TrackEntity` from the database given the `id` of that entity. I don't know what I'd have to do in order to make this work.

Answer (score -2):

Add the `@EnableAsync` to a configuration class and add `@Async("yourTaskExecuter")`.

The `@EnableAsync` annotation switches Spring’s ability to run `@Async` methods in a background thread pool.

Comment: async processing and async handling of requests are 2 different things. For the latter you don't need `@EnableAsync`.